# Как создать и заполнить hashmap из файла access.log

Tags: java, hashmap

Есть файл access.log, расположен он на  `C:\java`
и имеет структуру `время_длина запроса_ip-адрес_код/статус_байты данных_метод_URL_пользователь_источник_тип где '_'- пробел.`
Как заполнить HashMap?

Пример записи в файле acces.log:

```
1360425902.620      2 192.168.50.8 TCP_DENIED/403 3867 CONNECT gstat.imgsmail.ru:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Comment: во-первых, в идеале надо привести пример хотя бы одной строки лога. во-вторых, для начала попытаться сделать самостоятельно и показать результат, и последнее - уточнить, на каком именно этапе возникла проблема? а еще HashMap - это коллекция типа ключ-значение. из условия непонятно, что вы хотите сделать ключом, а что значением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Debug2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\java\\access.log");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
                String time = data[0];
                String ip = data[2];
                String url = data[8];
                // получаем другие данные по индексу в том порядке, в каком они идут в логах

                map.put(ip, url); // заполняем map, подставляем значения, какие хотим в ключ и значение
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

---

Пример с своим классом `IpData`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Debug2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\java\\access.log");

        Map<String, IpData> map = new HashMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
                String time = data[0];
                String ip = data[2];
                String url = data[8];
                // получаем другие данные по индексу в том порядке, в каком они идут в логах

                // создаем объект своего класса, в который сохраняем все данные, связанные с ip
                IpData ipData = new IpData();
                ipData.time = time;
                ipData.url = url;

                map.put(ip, ipData); // заполняем map, подставляем значения, какие хотим в ключ и значение
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    static class IpData {
        String time;
        String url;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если я хочу получить пару не map.put(ip, url), а map.put(ip, url, time) как это можно прописать чтобы не писать два раза map.put(ip, url) и map.put(ip, time) и не было повторений в итоге?

Comment: @beartree в map для каждого ключа может быть только одно значение. если вставить несколько раз, тогда в map останется последнее вставленное значение. чтобы сделать то, что вы хотите, нужно использовать свой класс, я в своем ответе добавил пример такого